# QlickView Join with loaded tables

Tags: join, qlikview

I have two simple inline tables loaded in qlikview as follows:

```
Fruits:
LOAD * INLINE
[
Fruit, Color
Mango, Yellow
Apple, Red
Orange, Orange
Grapes, Green
Blackberries, Black
];

Vegetables:
LOAD * INLINE
[
Vegetable, Color
Lemon, Yellow
Tomatoes, Red
Cucumbers, Green
];
```

Now **after loading**, is it possible to join the tables like so:

```
Inner Join (Fruits)
Vegetables
```

I know if I place the `Inner Join (Fruits)` before Vegetables: it would work. But how do I do it if I need the Vegetables table as well?

Comment: Can you show what you'd like your output table to look like? I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Still struggling to understand the QlikView modeling concepts. But RESIDENT is the word that I am look at. JoinTable:
Join (Fruits)
LOAD * Resident Vegetables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a load statement after the join. When you want to refer to a table already loaded use the Resident keyword.

here is how i would write it: `Inner Join (Fruits) load * Resident Vegetable;`